# How to make tab position in center screen in ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I create a custom tab bar in flutter and I want to center every tab tapped by the user, I have been trying like this but can not find the result

```
GlobalKey key = gkey[i];
    
RenderBox box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
double tabWidth = box.size.width;
    
ScrollController scroll = _categoryScrollController;
double maxScroll = scroll.position.maxScrollExtent;
double currentScroll = scroll.position.pixels;
    
double screenWidth = Get.width;

double pos = 0; // help me find the result

// scroll tab to center
 _categoryScrollController.animateTo(pos < 0 ? 0 : pos > maxScroll ? maxScroll : pos, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.ease);
```

Answer (score 1):

after I tried several time I found the result

```
GlobalKey key = gkey[i];
    
RenderBox box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
double tabWidth = box.size.width;
double tabPosition = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dx;
    
ScrollController scroll = _categoryScrollController;
double maxScroll = scroll.position.maxScrollExtent;
double currentScroll = scroll.position.pixels;
    
double screenWidth = Get.width;
double pos = (currentScroll + tabPosition) - (screenWidth / 2) + (tabWidth / 2);

_categoryScrollController.animateTo(pos < 0 ? 0 : pos > maxScroll ? maxScroll : pos, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.ease);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).